# Unit testing Rx binding with UITextView

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uitextview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a ControlProperty binding like this in my UIViewController:

```
textView.rx.text.orEmpty.asObservable()
    .bind(to: viewModel.descriptions)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

, where `viewModel.descriptions` is of type `BehaviorRelay<String>`.

In a TDD approach, I would like to write an (initially failing) test (as the initial step of the red-green-refactor cycle) to see that this binding exists. I tried with a test code like this:

```
sut.textView.insertText("DESC")
sut.textView.delegate?.textViewDidChange?(sut.textView)

expect(mockViewModel.lastDescriptions).to(equal("DESC"))
```

, where `sut` is my ViewController and `mockViewModel` contains code to subscribe to the `descriptions` `BehaviorRelay`:

```
class MockViewModel: MyViewModelProtocol {
    var descriptions = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
    var lastDescriptions: String?
    private var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init() {            
        descriptions.asObservable()
            .skip(1)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (title: String) in
                self?.lastDescriptions = title
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

However, I cannot push the new value to the `textView` so that the `descriptions` `BehaviorRelay` gets it.

How can I achieve `descriptions.asObservable()` to fire when entering a value in the `textView`? If it were a `UITextField` then I would do:

```
textField.text = "DESC"
textField.sendActions((for: .editingChanged))
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: IMHO there is nothing to test in that binding. Only test the dynamic behavior _you_ wrote. If you *really* feel the need, the only test that makes sense is to ensure that the code exists and that's it. You could do that using a regex on the file itself.

Comment: There may be additional RX operators before .bind and thats logic to test. (I tried to simplify the code above to reduce noise and focus on the problem.)

Comment: Then that logic should go into your ViewModel and you test that feeding data to it results in whatever it should. But you don't test the binding itself. RxSwift is in itself unit tested !

Comment: I do not want to test the binding itself. I am following a TDD approach and the "red" part of the red-green-refactor cycle when connecting the UITextView to the view-model is to write a test that such a binding exists.

Comment: That's fine, write the test if you feel you must, but the test needs to prove the correct thing. The question you are trying to answer with the test is "Is `textView` bound to `descriptions`?" You aren't testing behavior here, just whether or not the code exists. You can test existence by just loading the .swift file and running a regex over it.